# Transform a changeset property before it goes into the database

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I added a `textarea` to an Elixir form, and I set the value to a `string` and have got the string into a database metadata column that is of a `jsonb` type. The string in the `textarea` I wish to split by new-line and store an `array` of `strings` rather then just one big string.

I have since changed the type as follows.

```
field :names, {:array, :string}
```

However I am unsure how to use Ecto to intercept this data and split it before it enters the database.

I have looked at:

- [Ecto.Changeset](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html) Documentation
- [Phoenix: Ecto cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/phoenix-ecto)
- [Thinking in Ecto - schemas and changesets](http://cultofmetatron.io/2017/04/22/thinking-in-ecto---schemas-and-changesets/) Blog Post

It seems that I can add a `validation` function to the schema, this is my attempt.

```
def changeset(schema, params \\ %{}) do
    schema
    |> cast(params, @required, @optional)
    |> validate_name()
end

defp validate_names(changeset) do
    # fetch_field(changeset, :names)
    # Map.put(changeset, :names, String.split(:names, "\r\n"))
end
```

How do I change the value of one property in an Elixir object?

Update:

> person_metadata.ex

```
defmodule DB.PersonMetadata do
  use DB.Schema

  embedded_schema do
    field :names, :string
  end

  @required ~w()
  @optional ~w(names)

  def changeset(schema, params \\ %{}) do
    schema
    |> cast(params, @required, @optional)
    |> validate_names()
  end

  defp validate_names(changeset) do
    case get_field(changeset, :names) do
      # Don't do anything if names don't exist
      nil ->
        changeset

      # Update names if they do exist
      names ->
        new_names = String.split(names, "\n")
        put_change(changeset, :names, new_names)
    end
  end

  def types, do: @types
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```ex
defp validate_names(changeset) do
  case get_change(changeset, :names) do
    # Update name if it's a string
    names when is_binary(names) ->
      new_names = String.split(names, "\r\n")
      put_change(changeset, :names, new_names)

    # Don't do anything if nil or already an array
    _other ->
      changeset
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm getting an error `no function clause matching in String.split/3`.

Comment: Make sure that the term you are [splitting](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3) is actually a String and not already a List. You can try doing `IO.inspect`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the schema file system, it would seem there are two files.  One to render data for the view and one to handle the data going into the db. Ideally on read, the array is joined and on write the array is split. I am a bit confused how this works. The render is using `PhoenixSwagger` and the `get_field` function is not available.

Comment: I added the contents of both files.

Comment: I guess it might be a good idea to change `get_field` to `get_change` https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#get_change/3

Answer (score 3):

Seems the whole custom function can now (since when?) be replaced by [Ecto.Changeset.update_change/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#update_change/3)

```
 |> update_change(:names, fn
     nil -> nil # or preferably []?
     names -> String.split(names, ~r{\r?\n})
    end)
```

or as a matter of style

```
 |> update_change(:names, &my_name_splitter/1)
```